# Android FileInputStream changing path from file:/// to /file:/

Tags: android

I'm selecting a file from my devices download folder through a file select intent. The path returned is the correct format, ie:

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/Downloads/file.doc
```

However when I try and insert that path into a FileInputStream like this:

```
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
```

I get:

```
I/O Error: File not found at: /file:/mnt/sdcard/Downloads/file.doc
```

Could anyone explain why this is happening and what can be done to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: **file:///mnt/sdcard/Downloads/file.doc** is not the correct path in the filesystem

Comment: Yes. You should remove file:// from it first.

Comment: neither is /file:/mnt/sdcard/Downloads/file.doc

Comment: see greenapps advice

Comment: a `File` knows it's a file, use the path directly, not the Uri.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `URI` to create file

```
String path = "file:///mnt/sdcard/Downloads/file.doc";
URI uri = URI.create(path);
InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(uri));
```

Comment: If I try and use a uri it tries to load it without the file:// prefix and then I get a uri not absolute error

Comment: I have edited the answer, do you have error when you use it like this?

Comment: @PeterMeadley `uri not absolute`, I would assume you missed the leading `/`?